# Django Expired Session Message API

Tags: django, session

I'm currently using `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60*60` to expire a Django session in 1 hour. I need to give a message to the user saying their session has expired on the login page.

Is there a way to test if the session has been expired? Or is there a message api for expired sessions in Django?

I poked around and didn't see anything for setting an expired session message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning typically provided to a user is an invitation to login :-).

What you could do is check SESSION_COOKIE_AGE (which provides the age of the cookie in seconds) and, if the user's session is about to expire, provide a warning to that effect.

Comment: I'm not looking for a warning for an about-to-expire session. I need to flash the user on the login page, something like "Your session has expired. Please login again to continue checking out."

Answer (score 1):

To display the message that session is expired you can check if session exists in your logout view and change the success message accordingly

```
class Logout(View):
def get(self, request):
    if request.session:
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully Logged Out')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Session Expired Please Login Again')
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

Comment: If user's session expired, user automatically redirecting to LOGIN_URL internally when user refresh page and this view not running on session expiration. So this is not working correct.

Answer (score 0):

I encouraged same problem and solved shown as below:

Django redirecting to LOGIN_URL after session expired.
So I pointed login url to logout view in `settings.py` for show message to user 
and redirect to our login view.

`settings.py`:

```
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account:logout')
```

`views.py`:

```
class LogoutView(RedirectView):
    url = reverse_lazy('account:login') # Our login view

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        # If session expired django clean request.session object.
        # If user came to this view by clicking to logout button request.session not comes empty 
        if request.session.is_empty():
            messages.error(request, "Your session has expired. Please login again to continue checking out.")

        logout(request)

        if request.GET.get('next'):
            self.url = '{}?next={}'.format(self.url, request.GET.get('next'))

        return super(LogoutView, self).get(request, **kwargs)
```