# Auto end video call session from a page Django

Tags: django, session

I'm developing a custom video call app in Django. I want to end the video call session after 1 hour. Is there any way other than using JS or AJAX to auto exit from the page? Comment if you need more info

Comment: If you are asking for a **server-side** method, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200787/django-expired-session-message-api?rq=1) might help you.

Comment: Thanks. Here I’m not logging out the user. I just want the user to exit the page after a certain time period.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are looking for a way to redirect after 1 hour, server-side and without JS or AJAX?

Comment: @correctsyntax Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do specifically, but here is a minimal, working example (without JS or AJAX) which you should be able to modify to fit what you need.

It uses the principle of setting a cookie with a max age, etc like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200787/django-expired-session-message-api?rq=1)

The main thing that makes this work is setting the `http-equiv="refresh"` meta tag in the html to be the same period of time as the `max_age` of the cookie. That way, the page will auto-refesh just when the cookie (that we set) expires and the page will redirect without further input.

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
    
    
    def initial_page(request):
        # Set the cookie
        response = redirect("video-call")
    
        # You probably want to set it only once for each user and make this secure
        response.set_cookie( 
            "call_timeout", 
            "1",
            max_age=3600 # Set this to the time you need
            )
    
        return response
    
    
    def video_call_page(request):
        # See if the cookie has expired 
        # (This will auto-check because of the http-equiv="refresh" in the HTML)
        try:
            c = request.COOKIES['call_timeout'] # Try to access the cookie
            context = {}
            # The cookie hasn't expired, so continue
            return render(request, "vid_call.html", context)
    
        except KeyError:
            # The time is up, so redirect to the page of your choice
            return redirect("expire_redirect")
    
    
    def redirect_page(request):
        # The cookie expired
        context = {}
        return render(request, "redirect.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .views import initial_page, video_call_page, redirect_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', initial_page, name='initial'),
    url(r'^video-call/$', video_call_page, name='video-call'),
    url(r'^expired/$', redirect_page, name='expire_redirect'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

vid_call.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

<!-- Set http-equiv="refresh" to the same as the max_age param -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Video call page</h1>
    <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
      <!-- Set the path to a test video in your static dir (represents your video call) -->
      <source src="{% static 'mov_bbb.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
</body>
</html>
```

redirect.html is just the page content you want the user to be redirected to after an hour (or any other period of time, etc.) so I won't include it here.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definitely try this and let you know.

Comment: @PSN, did this answer your question? :)